# check if ip is available

Tags: bash, ip

Is it possible to check if ip is free with a script

pseudo code would look something like this

```
if [ip is available]
   echo "IP is available"
else
   echo "IP is not available"
fi
```

Can ping be used for this perhaps?

Comment: Define "available".

Comment: By available I mean if no other device is using the ip.

Comment: Device on your LAN or device on the internet?  Does using mean "sometimes uses this IP" or does it mean that the device is currently powered up and active?

Comment: this is not an answer to this question, but I find that it's very useful to run `arpwatch` or similar on either the central router / firewall or the machine running a DHCP daemon or major service used by most or all client machines (e.g. web proxy, file server).  It will log all MAC and IP address combos seen, and alert you when it sees new or changed addresses (e.g. a MAC address starts using an IP that was previously unused or being used by another MAC).  Of course, it can only see MAC addresses on network segments that it is **directly connected to**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your asking device already has an IP address then it's possible to get a fair attempt with `ping`

```
if ping -c1 -w3 10.11.12.13 >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Ping responded; IP address allocated" >&2
else
    echo "Ping did not respond; IP address either free or firewalled" >&2
fi
```

Notice that it's not possible to use this technique to differentiate between a host that's refusing to answer and one that isn't there.

Comment: Stuff like duplicate address detection will use multiple probes in case of packet loss (wireless!)  3 is probably traditional.  Also, without installing arping, you can follow up with `arp | grep 10.11.12.13` and detect a host on the local network even if it does block "ping". (If you use that method, the kernel will have done multiple probes for you even if you only sent one ping).

Comment: @sourcejedi yes I considered `arp` but decided that `ping` would be probably be sufficient for this question. Feel free to edit and improve the script. I've increased the wait time to three seconds as you recommended.

Answer (score 3):

In one sense this is impossible.

You can ask for a specific IP from a DHCP server.  IPv6 performs Duplicate Address Detection automatically.  In IPv4, DHCP clients are supposed to check for duplicate addresses using ARP (or equivalent).  The standard tools don't check for IPv4 collisions for static addresses though (unlike Windows).

But if you check for an IP *without* trying to allocate it, the IP could become unavailable immediately after your check (a "race condition").

DHCP address allocations do not suffer from this race condition, barring a network mis-configuration involving multiple conflicting DHCP servers.  IPv6 DAD should also prevent it.

[IPv4 DAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227) uses ARP probes, but it did not become a full standard.   I believe DHCPv4 doesn't specify the probes in any way, therefore it's likely that some implementations of it suffer from races.

As John pointed out, it's also possible there's a statically configured device which will (blindly) claim an IP, but it happens to be down right now.  If you need an IPv4 address, then acquiring it using DHCP is a nice option to let network administrators prevent such conflicts.